# Как исправить ошибку 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: apache, nginx

Раз в неделю стабильно перестают работать сайты. В браузере `Nginx` выводит `502 Bad Gateway`, в логах:

> 948#0: *398833 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 111.11.11.11, server: site.ru, request: "GET /private/auction_view/?id=55b8d3cc7d6ece71608b456b HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://111.1.111.11:7081/private/auction_view/?id=55b8d3cc7d6ece71608b456b", host: "site.ru"

Не помогает перезапуск `nginx`, `apache2`, `php5-fpm`. Только полная перезагрузка сервера.

Comment: А БД не используете? Например MySql?

Comment: *Раз в неделю* — cron.weekly?

Comment: MySql- используется.

Comment: cron.weekly- не в какое-то одно четкое время, сегодня ночью например, до этого утром было

Answer (score 1):

Вы не те логи смотрите. Если у вас `PHP`, то его логи и смотрите.
`/var/log/httpd/` или `/var/log/php-fpm/`.

Скорее всего у вас зависает БД, например `MySQL` и `PHP` очень долго к ней коннектиться или запрос долгий, из-за этого все воркеры у `Apache` (или `php-fpm`) висят и `Nginx` не может проксировать запрос на него.

Команды вам в помощь (если у вас Linux):

`htop`, `top`, `df -h`, `free -h`, `df -i`, `mpstat`, `dstat`

### UPD

Если логи `nginx`, `apache`, `php-fpm` ничего не дадут, то надо смотреть системные логи вашей ОС.

Comment: Добавлю, что если какой-то процесс падает или зависает и его нужно перепинывать, то можно использовать [monit](https://mmonit.com/)

Comment: Тогда по идее restart mysql должен был решить проблему на время. Но этого не происходит. + нет какой-то тяжелой задачи на одной какой-то странице. Перестают работать все сайты на сервере.

Comment: @user982125 а что вы еще используете для сайтов? Обычно тех команд, что я написал, хватает, что бы диагностировать проблему

Comment: Памяти из 16GB, использется только 1.5GB. Есть большое выделение виртуальной памяти http://joxi.ru/bmoO84oIM3339m

Comment: @user982125 я имел ввиду из технологий

Comment: memstat http://joxi.ru/8An07eXIqzzzZm

Comment: На одном из сайтов еще используется MongoDb, но памяти она не много отъедает пока

Comment: @user982125 логи после рестарта служб смотрели? Почему они не могу поднятся?